# Mysql nested select query inside having

Tags: mysql, nested, alias

Mysql says "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ju.id' in 'where clause'"

Why I can't use the alias `ju` inside the nested select. Is there any issue the way I have ordered the query?

```sql
SELECT `ac`.`name`, COALESCE(SUM(tr.amount*ju.rate), 0) as amount 
FROM `transactions` `tr` 
LEFT JOIN `journals` `ju` ON `tr`.`journal_id` = `ju`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `accounts` `ac` ON `ac`.`id` = `tr`.`account` 
WHERE `ju`.`txn_date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-01-01 00:00:00') 
  AND `ju`.`txn_date` <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-07-08 23:59:59') 
  AND `tr`.`type` = 'debit' 
  AND (`ac`.`bank` = 1 OR `ac`.`cash` = 1) 
  AND `ac`.`business` = 201 
GROUP BY `ac`.`id` 
HAVING ( SELECT tra.id 
         FROM transactions tra 
         LEFT JOIN accounts acc ON `acc`.`id` = `tra`.`account` 
         WHERE `tra`.`journal_id` = `ju`.`id` 
           AND `tra`.`type` = 'credit' 
           AND `acc`.`category` IN ('Sales Revenue','Other Income')
       ) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Nested loop? There is no such thing as a loop in SQL.

Comment: After `GROUP BY ac.id` the value of `ju.id` not exists. Try to use, for example, `MAX(ju.id)` (I hope that all `ju.id` values in a group are the same).

Comment: you joins are wrong. They will behave like inner join not outer.

Comment: @stickybit my bad it's a typo. edited the question should be nested "select"

Comment: @Akina got it working by using MAX(ju.id) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct explanation is that the subquery after HAVING (between the parenthesis) make the alias "ju" in the top level query out of scope.

I've never used HAVING before, but my solution would be to add the "journals" table to the subquery with the needed criteria. But that really depends on what you want to query for.

Comment: there is a main table called journals where I record journal entry common details such as date, currency etc...then there is a transactions table where I save each transaction related to journals (credits and debits). I want to select all the debit entries where there is a credit entry for that same journal entry linked to a 'Sales Revenue' or 'Other Income' category accounts